# In ggplot, How to reorder bars in a barplot according to height, while relocating specific bars to certain x axis positions?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a barplot, I want to both:

1. Reorder the bars from high to low, ***and***
2. Relocate one specific bar to the end, regardless of its value.

### Example

Here's fake data about frequency of letters. We have the frequency of letters `a`-`t`, and the rest are collapsed under `other`.

```r
d <- structure(
  list(
    letter = c(
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
      "d",
      "e",
      "f",
      "g",
      "h",
      "i",
      "j",
      "k",
      "l",
      "m",
      "n",
      "o",
      "p",
      "q",
      "r",
      "s",
      "t",
      "other"
    ),
    n = c(107, 106, 80, 65, 24, 23, 19, 17, 15, 10, 10,
          9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 97),
    percent = c(
      0.168769716088328,
      0.167192429022082,
      0.126182965299685,
      0.102523659305994,
      0.0378548895899054,
      0.0362776025236593,
      0.0299684542586751,
      0.026813880126183,
      0.0236593059936909,
      0.0157728706624606,
      0.0157728706624606,
      0.0141955835962145,
      0.0126182965299685,
      0.0126182965299685,
      0.0126182965299685,
      0.0110410094637224,
      0.00946372239747634,
      0.00788643533123028,
      0.00788643533123028,
      0.00788643533123028,
      0.152996845425868
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-21L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

d %>%
  print(n = 21)
#> # A tibble: 21 x 3
#>    letter     n percent
#>    <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 a        107 0.169  
#>  2 b        106 0.167  
#>  3 c         80 0.126  
#>  4 d         65 0.103  
#>  5 e         24 0.0379 
#>  6 f         23 0.0363 
#>  7 g         19 0.0300 
#>  8 h         17 0.0268 
#>  9 i         15 0.0237 
#> 10 j         10 0.0158 
#> 11 k         10 0.0158 
#> 12 l          9 0.0142 
#> 13 m          8 0.0126 
#> 14 n          8 0.0126 
#> 15 o          8 0.0126 
#> 16 p          7 0.0110 
#> 17 q          6 0.00946
#> 18 r          5 0.00789
#> 19 s          5 0.00789
#> 20 t          5 0.00789
#> 21 other     97 0.153
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Now let's say I want to plot `d`, and sort bars by the value of column `percent`.

```r
d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(letter, -percent), y = percent)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image: ordered_p]

**My question:**

What if I want to presevre the order of bars as above, ***but only change the location of `other`, moving it to the far right?***

Here's an illustration:

[image: illustration]

My apologies if this is a duplicate. I couldn't find a straightforward answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `forcats` option:

```
library(forcats); library(dplyr)
d %>%
  # first sort by descending percent, then move "other" to the end
  mutate(x = letter %>% fct_reorder(-percent) %>% fct_relevel("other", after = Inf)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = , y = percent)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: ups. you were first. i will delete.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
d$letter  <- factor(d$letter  , levels=c(letters[1:20],"other"))


d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = letter, y = percent)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Now let's pretend that the value for "s" is higher than all other values. You could try something like :

```
ranking <- reorder(d$letter,-d$percent)

d$letter  <- factor(d$letter  , levels=c(setdiff(levels(ranking),"other"),"other"))

d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x =  letter, y = percent)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]