# In ggplot, how to order bars from high-to-low, within-facet, and still relocate one specific bar to position of choice?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidytext

I want to create a bar plot with bars ordered from high to low, and preserve such ordering also when wrapping into facets. Fortunately, the package `{tidytext}` has a function `reorder_within()` that does exactly this. However, I couldn't find a way to apply such within-facet high-to-low reordering ***and*** manually reposition specific bars.

### Example

Below I'm adopting code from [this blog](https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/).
Let's say that we want to count baby names per decade.

#### Step 1 -- the data

We're going to visualize `top_names`, which is a subset of the `babynames` dataset.

```r
library(babynames)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

top_names <- 
  babynames %>%
  filter(between(year, 1950, 1990)) %>%
  mutate(decade = (year %/% 10) * 10) %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  count(name, wt = n, sort = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()

top_names
#> # A tibble: 123,205 x 3
#>    decade name         n
#>     <dbl> <chr>    <int>
#>  1   1950 James   846042
#>  2   1950 Michael 839459
#>  3   1960 Michael 836934
#>  4   1950 Robert  832336
#>  5   1950 John    799658
#>  6   1950 David   771242
#>  7   1960 David   736583
#>  8   1960 John    716284
#>  9   1970 Michael 712722
#> 10   1960 James   687905
#> # ... with 123,195 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

#### Step 2 -- prepare data for plot

```r
library(tidytext)
library(ggplot2)

data_for_plot <- 
  top_names %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  top_n(15) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
         name = reorder_within(name, n, decade))
#> Selecting by n

data_for_plot
#> # A tibble: 75 x 3
#>    decade name                n
#>    <fct>  <fct>           <int>
#>  1 1950   James___1950   846042
#>  2 1950   Michael___1950 839459
#>  3 1960   Michael___1960 836934
#>  4 1950   Robert___1950  832336
#>  5 1950   John___1950    799658
#>  6 1950   David___1950   771242
#>  7 1960   David___1960   736583
#>  8 1960   John___1960    716284
#>  9 1970   Michael___1970 712722
#> 10 1960   James___1960   687905
#> # ... with 65 more rows
```

#### Step 3 -- Visualize

```r
p_so_far_so_good <- data_for_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, n, fill = decade)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))

p_so_far_so_good
```

[image: plotted_nicely]

---

### So far, so good!

Now, in each facet (i.e., "decade"), I want to lump together all bars except for the top 15. While the top 15 should remain as-is, the rest should be grouped as "other". Furthermore, I want to visualize this new categorization in a way that **preserves** the high-to-low order of bars, but nevertheless tacks the "other" bar at the bottom. I've already posted [such a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68730143/in-ggplot-how-to-reorder-bars-in-a-barplot-according-to-height-while-relocatin), but the solution given there isn't working for the within-facet situation.

### My unsuccessful attempt #1

Some wrangling to create the "other" category per group.

```r
data_for_plot_with_other <-
  top_names %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  arrange(decade, desc(n)) %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(row_number() < 5, name, "other")) %>%
  group_by(decade, name) %>%
  summarise(across(n, sum)) %>%
  arrange(name == "other", -n, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
         name = reorder_within(name, n, decade))

> data_for_plot_with_other %>% print(n = 20)
## # A tibble: 75 x 3
##    decade name                   n
##    <fct>  <fct>              <int>
##  1 1950   James___1950      846042
##  2 1950   Michael___1950    839459
##  3 1950   Robert___1950     832336
##  4 1950   John___1950       799658
##  5 1950   David___1950      771242
##  6 1950   Mary___1950       627098
##  7 1950   William___1950    592423
##  8 1950   Linda___1950      565481
##  9 1950   Richard___1950    536393
## 10 1950   Patricia___1950   460643
## 11 1950   Thomas___1950     455154
## 12 1950   Susan___1950      438419
## 13 1950   Deborah___1950    431302
## 14 1950   Mark___1950       383076
## 15 1950   other___1950    30863329 ## see how "other" closes the decade = 1950 group
## 16 1960   Michael___1960    836934
## 17 1960   David___1960      736583
## 18 1960   John___1960       716284
## 19 1960   James___1960      687905
## 20 1960   Robert___1960     653556
# ... with 55 more rows
```

#### visualize

```r
data_for_plot_with_other %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, n, fill = factor(decade))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image: not_what_i_want]

**This is not what I want.**[image]


What I do want is something like the following:
[image: demo]

### My unsuccessful attempt #2

In the spirit of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68731198/6105259), I tried also releveling the factor `name`.
I built a helper function that detects the substring `other_` and moves it to the end (of group).

```r
move_to_end <- function(x, match_to_pattern = "other_") {
  which_idx <- grep(pattern = match_to_pattern, x = x)
  c(x[-which_idx], x[which_idx])
}

data_for_plot_with_other %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  mutate(across(name, ~fct_relevel(.x, move_to_end))) %>%
  ## then the visualization as before
  ggplot(aes(name, n, fill = factor(decade))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image: same]

Still, the same output.

### In sum

How can I get the bars ordered high-to-low *within facets* **and** have the "other" bar always at the very bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do this using:

- `forcats::fct_lump_n()` to create the "Other" category within each decade, using the `w` argument to weight by the frequencies we have counted up
- `forcats::fct_relevel()` to move the newly created "Other___" levels to the beginning of the big overall factor

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(babynames)

top_names <- 
    babynames %>%
    filter(between(year, 1950, 1990)) %>%
    mutate(decade = (year %/% 10) * 10) %>%
    group_by(decade) %>%
    count(name, wt = n, sort = TRUE, name = "total") %>%
    ungroup()


library(tidytext)

data_for_plot <- 
    top_names %>%
    group_by(decade) %>%
    mutate(name = fct_lump_n(name, n = 15, w = total)) %>%
    group_by(decade, name) %>%
    mutate(total = sum(unique(total))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    distinct(decade, name, total) %>%
    mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
           name = reorder_within(name, total, decade),
           name = fct_relevel(name, paste0("Other___", unique(decade))))

data_for_plot %>%
    ggplot(aes(total, name, fill = decade)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
    facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
    scale_y_reordered() +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It makes more sense to sort descending then use `summarize()` to ensure the `"others"` appear last, and from then on, it's just a matter of factorizing by taking the order by which they appear:

```
dat = top_names %>%
      group_by(decade) %>%
      arrange(decade, desc(n)) %>%
      summarize(decade = mean(decade),
            name = c(name[1:15],"others"),
            n = c(n[1:15],sum(n) - sum(n[1:15]))
            ) %>%
      mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
         name = reorder_within(name, n():1, decade))

ggplot(dat,aes(name, n, fill = factor(decade))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! As far as I can see, the difference between your `dat` to my `data_for_plot_with_other` boils down to how `reorder_within()` is called. Whereas I called `reorder_within(name, n, decade)` under no grouping, you did `reorder_within(name, n():1, decade)` when grouped by `decade`.

Comment: In other words, I aggregated the data correctly (though not concisely), but didn't use `reorder_within()` correctly.

Comment: not really.. as mentioned in the post, the key is to order the names correctly so the above re-order can be used. If you look at your code, the others is often jumbled between names, so the reordering will be more complicated than it needs to be

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie but you can ? Fct_infreq() to get this done

Comment: Hello there and welcome to stack overflow. A link to a solution (or documentation) without expanding on why that is the solution or showing how the solution works for the use case, is typically not considered a full answer to a question.